# Assigning data from ruby on rails table to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to assign a javascript variable data from ror. I already made the query, and it gives me what i want (a single integer), but i can't assign it to a js variable. Here is the js script i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var number_of_products = '<%= Post.where(:id => 1).select(:amount).pluck(:amount)[0] %>';  
    $(document).ready(function(){
      for (i=1; i <=number_of_products; i++) $('#itemsAmount').append('<img src="images/box.svg"/>');
    })
  })
</script>
```

But i can't seem to pass the ror value (`<%= Post.where(:id => 1).select(:amount).pluck(:amount)[0] %>`) to the js variable (`number_of_products`)

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Shai.

Comment: What is the final output when you view source in the browser?

Comment: Thanks. for the script part in the source i get: <script type="text/javascript">
    function() {
        var number_of_products = '70';  
        $(document).ready(function(){
          for (i=1; i <=number_of_products; i++) $('#itemsAmount').append('<img src="images/box.svg"/>');
      })
    }
</script>

Comment: In that case the value seems to be there, maybe its a different problem?

Comment: it seems that the value is in string, i need it as an integer. Maybe that's my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem your problem isn't with getting the value into javascript, its simply the wrong type  try and change your code to the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var number_of_products = <%= Post.where(:id => 1).select(:amount).pluck(:amount)[0] %>;  
    $(document).ready(function(){
      for (i=1; i <=number_of_products; i++) $('#itemsAmount').append('<img src="images/box.svg"/>');
    })
  })
</script>
```

**Edit:**

Do you have `#itemsAmount` on your page?

[Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DeMd2/](http://jsfiddle.net/DeMd2/)

Comment: Thanks. Now i do get an integer. Still can't use it in the second part of my js function: `for (i=1; i <=number_of_products; i++) $('#itemsAmount').append('<img src="images/box.svg"/>');`

Comment: I do have `#itemsAmount` on my page, and it still doesn't work. But thanks, i guess it means that it **should** work...

Comment: Have you checked your html to see if there is something wrong with the images? In modern browsers you can right click and `inspect element`

Comment: yes. well, the "static" version of this page works. I started by assigning the value manually and it worked. Then i moved to ROR, and got stuck.

Comment: Solved! thanks you so much. I went back to the early version and there i didn't have the `$function() {` part of the script. For some reason it caused this issue...